# If I publish an app to the google play store what stops people from stealing my code?

Tags: java, android, anti-piracy

I ask this question because I couldn't find the answer I was looking for but simply put is there anything in place in the app store to prevent stolen code? I notice that there are a lot of clones on android which made me wonder whether they are directly ripped off or just so easy to replicate that they end up cloned. 
Can people just simply download the apk file and reverse engineer it?

Is there anything google has in place that prevents this, or if there isn't, is there anyway that I myself can prevent it or make it more difficult for people wanting to steal my code?

I'm still new to Java and learning so it will be a while before I start this, but the project I have in mind will consume a large chunk of what little spare time that I have for a while, so I don't want to put a lot of time into it without proper measures only to have it stolen and sold for someone else's profit in a week.

If this has been answered before whether on this site or another please point me to there and delete this if necessary.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Comment: ... well, maybe honesty ...

Comment: App code as such generally isn't really worth stealing.

Comment: To be realistic, if you are new to Java and doing this in your spare time, it will probably be quite a long time before you are producing app-store quality code.  I suggest focusing your energy on learning the technology and not worrying about this very unlikely scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can do **code obfuscation**, so that on de-compiling the code, the logic is not obvious, so hard to maintain.

You can use the free version i.e. [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) or much powerful professional version [DexGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/dexguard).

Here is an example which shows how to configure ProGuard when you are using libraries. 
[Retrofit+ProGuard](http://ramannanda.blogspot.com/2015/03/proguard-configuration-for-retrofit.html).