# Protecting Software from Copying / Piracy

Tags: copy-protection, anti-piracy

I'm interested in protecting some software I've developed from piracy and theft and whatnot.

I feel I have created a piece of marketable software. It's nothing massively groundbreaking, just a Photoshop script I made to help my parents, and I went to and beyond the scope I was given, but I feel now it has some potential.

In layman's terms, how would I go about preventing my software from being pirated or being distributed without my knowledge? I know that anti-piracy methods are hardly ever secure against people who are really persistent, but I want to make it so that the average Joe can't go and redistribute my software, and to make it an inconvenience to those who are focused on pirating my software. I know about obfuscating software but that's really only a mild inconvenience to a seasoned hacker who can recognize what cipher is being used, so what else can I do?

Comment: I think this question is too broad, in its current form, to get a lot of useful help. I'd encourage you to decide: 1. how to you plan to distribute your software, and what form will it have? Is it a standalone app, a web app, a plugin for Photoshop, etc. Will users navigate to your website, download it from you, or get it from a repository like the iTunes store? And, 2. do you want to make the source code public (open-source)?

Comment: Also, do any of the following answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55858250/how-to-ensure-my-software-is-not-easy-to-pirate 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000631/if-i-publish-an-app-to-the-google-play-store-what-stops-people-from-stealing-my
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56857319/basic-precautions-to-prevent-piracy